# How to find a function's memory address with lldb?

Tags: gdb, lldb

In GDB, I can use "info line func_name" to get the memory address of func_name, and then use "set $PC=memory_address" to start debugging this function. How do I do the same within lldb? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The command in lldb is "image lookup".  I think an example of "info func" <-> "image lookup" was recently added to the lldb/gdb command page - http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

e.g.

```
(lldb) im loo -n puts
1 match found in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib:
        Address: libsystem_c.dylib[0x0000000000011d9a] (libsystem_c.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 69850)
        Summary: libsystem_c.dylib`puts
(lldb)
```

although this is only showing you the offset in libsystem_c.dylib here (0x11d9a) -- to see the actual load address you would need to use the "-v" option to image lookup which will show the range of addresses that puts covers.  Or you could do this more directly with the back tick notation in lldb,

```
(lldb) reg read pc
     rip = 0x0000000100000f2b  a.out`main + 11 at a.c:3
(lldb) reg write pc `(void(*)())puts`
(lldb) reg read pc
     rip = 0x00007fff99ce1d9a  libsystem_c.dylib`puts
```

OK I had to cast puts() because lldb needed a function prototype here - not super convenient, but if it's one of your own functions that isn't needed:

```
(lldb) reg write pc `main`
(lldb) reg read pc
     rip = 0x0000000100000f20  a.out`main at a.c:2
```